# Help with Multiple Document Interface(MDI)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I'm new in Visual Studio 2010 and I an creating an application that saves the information of the Company and its Employees. I already created 2 forms. In the first form is the main menu where I put 2 panel in it, the left side has the button for Company and Employees and on the right side is where I want the 2nd form(form for Company) to display whenever I click the button for Company. Please help.

I know that I should use the MDIParent/MDIChild, but I don't have any idea how to start it.

[image: 1st form]

[image: 2nd form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make MDI any form F1, set isMDI property of the form F1 to true. When ever you open a new form F2, set F2.MdiParent = F1, and framework will take care of everything.